# How to reorder a ul li list by clicking on an link or button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, click

I need to move some selected items from a list by clicking on a link or button.

Giving 4 options to the user:
Put all selected items once backward or forward, or instead put all to the top of the list or to the bottom of the list.

I found a Jquery plugin that I'm using called [jquery.tinysort.js](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)

Actually, I don't need to use this plugin, could be any plugin or code, just need to work properly.

Follow a link to see a demo http://jsfiddle.net/dkwZZ/

Follow the html code:

```
    <div>
        <p>
            <a onclick="$('ul#ordenar>li').tsort({attr:'id'});">REFRESH ORDER</a> or 
            <a onclick="$('ul#ordenar>li').tsort('div[class=checkTrue]');">ALL SELECTED TO TOP</a> or 
            <a onclick="$('ul#ordenar>li').tsort('div[class=checkFalse]');">ALL SELECTED TO BOTTOM</a> or 
            <a>ALL SELECTED ONCE UP</a> or
            <a>ALL SELECTED ONCE DOWN</a> 
        </p>
        <ul class="" id="ordenar">
            <li id="0"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste0</li>
            <li id="1"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste1</li>
            <li id="2"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste2</li>
            <li id="3"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste3</li>
            <li id="4"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste4</li>
            <li id="5"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste5</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

When ALL SELECTED ONCE UP the order of the list should be:

```
        <ul class="" id="ordenar">
            <li id="0"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste0</li>
            <li id="1"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste1</li>
            <li id="3"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste3</li>
            <li id="2"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste2</li>
            <li id="5"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste5</li>             
            <li id="4"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste4</li>
        </ul>
```

When ALL SELECTED ONCE DOWN the order of the list should be:

```
        <ul class="" id="ordenar">
            <li id="1"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste1</li>
            <li id="0"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste0</li>
            <li id="2"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste2</li>
            <li id="4"><div class="checkFalse"></div>checkFalse teste4</li>
            <li id="3"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste3</li>
            <li id="5"><div class="checkTrue"></div>checkTrue teste5</li>
        </ul>
```

I will be eternally grateful if someone can help me.
Cheers!!!

Comment: Have you checked out http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#default There may be options to do what you're looking for.

Comment: Yeah I saw before, but it's drag'n drop, I need something by clicking... anyway tks for the tip dude!

Comment: First of, an ID should probably not start with a number, secondly, what exactly is the sorting order, I just don't get it? In the first example the list is sorted by ID or class, but in the two last examples there does not seem to be a system, neither ID or class is consistent, so what exactly should they be sorted by?

Comment: Yes, I get how you order them by class in the first example, either all checkTrue is at the top or bottom, but what is "once up" and "once down", I'm just not seeing the pattern, one is ordered every other class, and the other one does not seem to have any particular order?

Comment: Hi Adeno tks for reply.
We are using .NET code as back end development, so the list came with ID as numbers. This example is just the front end part.
Here we have two types of class "checkTrue" and "checkFalse". With that we can identify the item in two groups. They should be sorted/reorder based on that condition.
Therefore, we have 4 options to reorder the items:
1. All items "checkTrue" to the top of the list.
2. All items "checkTrue" to the bottom of the list.
3. All items "checkTrue" move up one line.
4. All items "checkTrue" move down one line.

Hope you can help, tks for your time.

Comment: Ah, I see, or rather I don't see! In the once up example the first element matches the class "checkTrue", but it is not moved one line up, which would really mean it should be at the bottom of the list, instead you keep the two first items untouched, and just trade places with the other items. Same goes for the bottom element in the "once down" example. Is this intended?

Comment: Humm. I think that's it. You see the iten 3 for example goes before item 2, after you click  ALL SELECTED ONCE UP, but at the same time the item 0 doesn't move because he can't move upper. The same thing for the item 5 when you clcik ALL SELECTED ONCE DOWN, this item it's the last of the list that's why he can't move further down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I get it now, here's something that should sort your elements without a plugin.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dkwZZ/27/)

```
var ul=$("#ordenar");

function sortList(ul, order) {
    var list=ul.children("li").get();
    switch(order) {
        case 'id' :
            list.sort(function(a, b) {
               var compA = $(a).attr('id'), compB = $(b).attr('id');
               return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
            });
            $.each(list, function(idx, itm) { ul.append(itm); });
            break;
        case 'class=True' :
            list.sort(function(a, b) {
                var compA = $(b).children(':first').attr('class'), 
                    compB = $(a).children(':first').attr('class');
               return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
            });
            $.each(list, function(idx, itm) { ul.append(itm); });
            break;
        case 'class=False' :
            list.sort(function(a, b) {
                var compA = $(a).children(':first').attr('class'), 
                    compB = $(b).children(':first').attr('class');
               return (compA < compB) ? -1 : (compA > compB) ? 1 : 0;
            });
            $.each(list, function(idx, itm) { ul.append(itm); });
            break;
        case 'one-up' :
            $.each(list, function() {
                if ($(this).children(':first').hasClass('checkTrue')) {
                    var prev = $(this).prev();
                    if (prev.length&&prev.children(':first').hasClass('checkFalse')) {prev.before($(this));}
                }
            });
            break;
        case 'one-down' :
            $.each(list, function() {
                if ($(this).children(':first').hasClass('checkTrue')) {
                    var next = $(this).next();
                    if (next.length&&next.children(':first').hasClass('checkFalse')) {next.after($(this));}
                }
            });
            break;
    }
}
```

Then stick some ID's on those `<a>` elements, and bind the clicks, use preventDefault if you're having issues with the window jumping to the top or other trouble with anchors.

```
$("#refresh").on('click', function() {sortList(ul, 'id');});
$("#to_top").on('click', function() {sortList(ul, 'class=True');});
$("#to_bot").on('click', function() {sortList(ul, 'class=False');});
$("#once_up").on('click', function() {sortList(ul, 'one-up');});
$("#once_down").on('click', function() {sortList(ul, 'one-down');});
```

Comment: Just one thing, if we have more than 1 item "checkTrue" together and we click once down, just the last Item comes down, instead they should all comes down together.

Comment: @user1309015 - Yes, I see that now, there was an issue when clicking once up, and all of them where at the top, they would not all come down again because the first one would move down, then the next one would move down and the first one would move up again etc. hard to explain in this short answer, I tried fixing it by only moving them if there was a checkFalse below, but that does not seem to be the right way to do it, but I think reversing the order would fix it, like in this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/dkwZZ/28/).